# Searching / Ordering data with inherited_resources in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin, inherited-resources

Is there a popular gem that makes it easier to build an admin interface in Rails that lets you search and order data? Bonus points if it integrates well with inherited_resources.

I don't want to use something as heavyweight as activeadmin.

Looking for something like this:
[image: image of goal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the sorted gem (https://github.com/mynameisrufus/sorted), which allows me to easily build sortable tables.

Ransack (https://github.com/ernie/ransack) lets me easily build searches.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you provided is exactly what you are looking for

http://activeadmin.info/

Comment: I updated my question to indicate that I don't want something as heavy as activeadmin. This needs to integrate into the rest of the UI.